# How to get data from an array inside json data php

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I have the following array of json data. When I try to loop using a for each, php gives me the error "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string". I want to access the nameserver in the authns array, and the soa array. How do I go about doing that?

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [error] => 
    [domain] => whoisdoma.net 
    [ip_address] => 108.162.199.120   
    [authns] => stdClass Object ( 
        [nameserver] => uma.ns.cloudflare.com 
        [ip] => 173.245.58.146 
        [location] => San Francisco 
    ) 
    [soa] => stdClass Object ( 
        [nameserver] => tom.ns.cloudflare.com 
        [email] => dns.cloudflare.com 
        [serial] => 2015505396 
        [refresh] => 10000 
        [retry] => 2400 
        [expiry] => 604800 
        [minimum] => 3600 
    )
)
```

This is the code I'm using to get the data:

```
 <?php
 $domain = $_GET['domain'];
//set the url
$url = "http://api.site.ga/v1/dns/lookup?domain=".$domain;

//start a curl session
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;

//set curl options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

//get the data
$data = curl_exec($ch);

//decode the data
$jsonData = json_decode($data);

//close the curl session
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

This is the for each loop I'm using

```
<?php 

foreach($jsonData->authns as $authns)
{
    echo $authns->nameserver;
}

?>
```

Comment: First things first. Have you converted it from json using `json_decode()`? If so try: `$object->authns->nameserver`. In any case, what is it exactly that you're doing which throws that error

Comment: Yes I have, just added the code I'm using to do that

Comment: so when is the error thrown?

Comment: its thrown at the for each loop when I use the authns variable

Comment: Can you do a full var_dump of $jsonData and post it in a pastebin?

Comment: You need to send a second parameter to json_decode() to make it associative. I answered the question with the sample code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to decode the json object using an associative array.

Here is an exmaple:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.domain.com/call'), true);
```

$data is now an associative array.

Comment: He didn't send the 'true' parameter to json_decode(); That is why he can't access elements in the array.

Comment: Now I see "Illegal string offset 'nameserver'", the code for that is "<?php foreach($jsonData['authns'] as $nsData): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $nsData['nameserver']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>"

Comment: Do a print_r($data); so that you see how the array is being structured.

Answer (score 2):

You are looping through `authns` while it is an object by itself. So your `nameserver` which you want is actually `$authns` in its first iteration.

Just access it like `$jsonData->authns->nameserver`

try this for yourself

```
foreach($jsonData->authns as $authns)
{
    echo $authns;
}
```